# Using MailKit for a long queue of emails

Tags: email, smtpclient, mailkit

We currently use SmtpClient to send emails, we usually have around 1000-5000 emails per day. We are having some performance issues, sometimes the Send command takes a very long time. Upon researching, I learned about MailKit and how it replaced SmtpClient. Reading through examples, every single one calls for

```
            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

            client.Send (message);
            client.Disconnect (true);
            }
```

With Disconnect after every message. If I'm planning to send many messages in sequence, should I still call a new SmtpClient instance for each one and Disconnect it? What is the proper way to handle a long sequence of email sends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to disconnect after sending a single message. You can keep calling the Send() method over and over until you are done sending messages.

A simple example might look like this:

```
static void SendALotOfMessages (MimeMessage[] messages)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
        client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

        // send a lot of messages...
        foreach (var message in messages)
            client.Send (message);

        client.Disconnect (true);
    }
}
```

A more complex example would take into consideration handling of [SmtpProtocolException](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpProtocolException.htm) and `IOException` which typically mean that the client got disconnected.

If you get an `SmtpProtocolException` or an `IOException`, you are guaranteed to need to reconnect. Those exceptions are always fatal.

[SmtpCommandException](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpCommandException.htm), on the other hand, is typically not fatal and you will normally not need to reconnect. You can always check the `SmtpClient.IsConnected` property to verify.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!